# How to subset and create a scatterplot with different symbols for groups?

Tags: r, subset, scatter-plot

I am analyzing data from aid organizations, some of which are multilateral and some are bilateral.

I want to select only the bilaterals and assign them to a variable and the same for multilaterals.

How can I do this?

Here are the data files https://dl.dropbox.com/u/56475675/datos_aid_R.ZIP

```
> short<-scan("short.txt",what=list(""))
Read 72 records
> country<-scan("country.txt")
Read 72 items
> total<-scan("total.txt")
Read 72 items
> short<-scan("short.txt",what=list(""))
Read 72 records
> donortag<-scan("donortag.txt",what=list(""))
Read 72 records
> total<-scan("total.txt")
Read 72 items
> organization<-scan("organization.txt")
Read 72 items
> country<-scan("country.txt")
Read 72 items
> activity<-scan("activity.txt")
Read 72 items
```

After subsetting I will create a scatter plot with labels, but I would like to draw bilateral with a red square (for example), and the multilaterals with a blue circle (for example),...

How can I use different plotting symbols in a scatter plot?

Here you can see what I have done in R

[http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8844/snap1226.png http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8844/snap1226.png](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/8844/snap1226.png).

Comment: These are very basic questions. Please read an introduction to R.

Answer (score 0):

It's not absolutely clear what you want on the axes of the scatterplot, but something along the lines of:

```
d <- data.frame(short,total,country,donortag,activity)
d2 <- droplevels(subset(d,donortag %in% c("Bilateral","Multilateral")))
cols <- c("red","blue")
pchs <- 1:2
with(d2,plot(total,activity,col=cols[donortag],pch=pchs[donortag]))
```

or

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(total,activity,data=d2,colour=donortag,pch=donortag)
```